# BeautifulSoup парсинг ozon.ru метод select выделяет только 2 товара

Tags: python, парсер, selenium, beautiful-soup

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36")
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
options.add_argument("--headless")

s = Service(executable_path="/lib/chromedriver")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=s)
driver.get('https://www.ozon.ru/search/?from_global=true&text=холодильник')

html = driver.page_source

driver.close()
driver.quit()

soup = bs(html, 'html.parser')

with open('page.html', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(str(soup.prettify()).encode('utf-8', 'ignore'))

result = soup.select('div[class*="widget-search-result-container"]')[0]

with open('result.html', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(str(result.prettify()).encode('utf-8', 'ignore'))
```

Если открыть файл `page.html`, то страница выглядит как надо, но в `result.html` находится только первые 2 товара. Структура сайта сохраняется, есть div и указаны их классы, но они пустые, в отличие от первых двух товаров. Еще я заметил что у первых двух товаров в `result.html` класс отличается от остальных, у первых двух класс `pi3 p3i`, у остальных `io9`, хотя они все должны быть `pi3 p3i`, не понятно откуда они вообще взялись